# stash and then pop in git does an auto commit

Tags: git, github

Folks,

I am a little new to stashing in git so may be I missing something basic here, this is what I am doing:

- I am on my master branch and I have been working on a file app/models/medicine.rb , I want to pull changes  from master pushed by my co-worker. So I do a **git stash**
- Now I do a **git pull origin master** this pulls all the new changes
- Now I do a **git stash pop**, it complains that there are merge conflicts I fix them
- Now when I do a **git diff app/models/medicine.rb** I do not see any of the changes that I had stashed in diff. Also when I do a **git log** I do not see my work committed anywhere.

So looks like those changes that I was working on got committed, I was not expecting that to happen. I wanted to work further and then do a commit. So is my understanding of stash wrong? What if I have a use case, where I am working on something and then I am not ready to commit yet but want to pull and then continue  to work further and then do a commit, what is the right git process for this?  Also the other side effect is there is no sha for my stashed work now, lets say I want to go back at some point to my work or cherry pick my work there is no way to do that. I dont even see it in my git log. Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Comment: `git status` is your friend

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The changes are not committed, but they are staged.  To see them, do `git diff --cached`.  To unstage them, do `git reset`.

Comment: thanks a lot, you are right. I just tried it. So basically its equivalent to this scenario **git add app/models/medicine.rb**, after this if I do a **git diff app/models/medicine.rb** I would not see anything.